# Change type of input depending on a dropdown in Angular?

Tags: html, angular

I have a dropdown next to an input field and I'm trying to create the input field such that it could dynamically change its `type` depending on the value selected in the dropdown. So if the user selects 'Text' from the dropdown, the type of the input would be 'text'.

Here is my HTML:

```
            <div class="input-group"">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="addCardio">Name</span>
              </div>
              <select
                class="form-control"
                [ngModel]="cardioInputType"
                [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
              >
                <option value="text">Text</option>
                <option value="number">Number</option>
              </select>
              <input
                  class="form-control"
                  [type]="cardioInputType"
              />
            </div>
```

Here is my TS file:

```
  cardioInputType: string = 'text';

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

There aren't any errors but it doesn't seem to change when I select a dropdown value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 2 way binding in `ngModel`

Change

```
<select
    class="form-control"
    [ngModel]="cardioInputType"
    [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
>
```

To

```
<select
    class="form-control"
    [(ngModel)]="cardioInputType"
    [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
>
```

Demo: https://angular-ivy-brdaba.stackblitz.io/

Answer (score 0):

just use two way data binding `[()]` for your ngModel

```
[(ngModel)]="cardioInputType"
```